# Best practice for authentication and authorization for spring based java application

Tags: spring, authentication, authorization, openldap, opensso

In our organization we are developing an ldap based Authentication, and Authorization
with Single Sign On on feature. Upon developing this generic module, there will be tens of other modules which will be dependent on it. The tool sets are -

- Spring
- Hibernate
- Tomcat 7
- openAm/openSSO
- openldap
- postgresql

We will have simple authentication mechanism but very complex authorization scheme. We are not sure what will be the right approach for authorization. Should we put the authentication as well as authorization logic in LDAP or should we use it for authentication only? In that case we will have to mess around with the OpenAM/OpenSSO. Is there any other approach? like spring security, CAS, JOSSO, .. ? Whatever the approach, it has to be very scalable and maintainable. Any suggestion or help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Nazrul

Comment: 1 year + 0 accepted answers = no help.

Answer (score 3):

You may have a look at Apache Shiro: http://shiro.apache.org/. It is a easy-to-use security framework that supports most of the existing security technologies including LDAP and Single Sign On.

Also, through subtyping AuthenticatingRealm and AuthorizingRealm (from the Shiro API), you can implement your authenticating and authorizing strategies no matter how complex they are.

Most commonly, you will implement your own:

- AuthenticatingRealm
- AuthorizingRealm
- AuthenticationToken
- AuthrozationToken
- PremissionResolver

  and so on...

Answer (score 1):

You probably would want to look at this before you move on in making any decision. 
http://grzegorzborkowski.blogspot.com/2008/10/spring-security-acl-very-basic-tutorial.html

Answer (score 1):

For the authorization, you can look at externalized authorization frameworks based on XACML, the [eXtensible Access Control Markup Language](http://oasis-open.org/committees/tc_home.php?wg_abbrev=xacml).

It is an OASIS standard that implements attribute-based access control which gives you a lot of flexibility into how you design your authorization.